# How to detect date selection in ng-bootstrap Datepicker on input field?

Tags: html, angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

We use the [ng-bootstrap Datepicker as Directive](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbInputDatepicker) in our project:

```
<input class="form-control"
         name="dp" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (blur)="d.close()" [(ngModel)]="model"
         (ngModelChange)="onDateSelected()">
```

The **current** behaviour is that `onDateSelected()` is called when a date in the datepicker is selected, as well as every time a change is made to the input field.

The **desired** behaviour is that `onDateSelected()` is called whenever the user clicks on a date in the datepicker or moves the cursor out of the `<input>` (i.e. blur).

My approach was to change `(ngModelChange)` to `(blur)`:

```
<input class="form-control"
         name="dp" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (blur)="d.close(); onDateSelected()"
         [(ngModel)]="model">
```

but this leads to `onDateSelected()` *not* being called, when a date is selected from the datepicker - which kinda makes sense, because the cursor is not inside the `<input>`. However, I could not find some sort of `dateSelected`-Event when searching the [ng-bootstrap docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbInputDatepicker) on which I could call `onDateSelected()`:

```
<input class="form-control"
         name="dp" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (blur)="d.close(); onDateSelected()"
/* missing -> */ (dateSelected)="onDateSelected()" /* <- */ [(ngModel)]="model">
```

Is there something I miss? Or maybe another way to implement this behaviour? I can't think of being the only one with this requirement...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Meanwhile, the [issue](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2181) has been closed and there will be a (dateSelect) event in 1.1.0: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/pull/2254

Comment: The event only fires when you select a date using the calendar. NOT when typing in a date manually.

Comment: I know your comemtn i

Comment: @emirhosseini I know your comment is quite old, but now select is depricated and dateSelect still does not seem to fire on typing

Answer (score 6):

```
<input class="form-control"
     name="dp" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (blur)="d.close()" 
[(ngModel)]="model"
     (select)="onDateSelected()">
```

This will work and `onDateSelected()` is called whenever you select a date in datepicker

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution:

```
<input 
class="form-control"    
name="startDate" 
[(ngModel)]="startDate"
(dateSelect)="doSomething()"
(blur)="doSomething()"
ngbDatepicker 
#startDate="ngbDatepicker"
>
```

Here (dateSelect) handles choosing from the calendar picker and (blur) handles manually input when the input loses focus.

Answer (score 1):

Guess `select` output method is what you are looking for.

> Select: An event fired when user selects a date using keyboard or mouse. The payload of the event is currently selected NgbDateStruct.

Refer the [output section](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api)

Comment: (select) only applies to NgbDatepicker *Component*. I'm using the NgbInputDatepicker *Directive* here, with which (select) does not work unfortunately.

Comment: From the code you shared i can only see `NgbDatepicker` being used. Should you update your code?

Comment: That's because the selector of the NgbInputDatepicker Directive is also 'ngbDatepicker': https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples (second demo)

Or did I mess something up?

Comment: This only fires for me when I select a date using the calendar. NOT when typing in a date into the input field manually!

Answer (score 0):

Using `dateSelect` worked for me:

```
<input class="form-control"
     name="dp" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (blur)="d.close(); ()onDateSelected()"
     [(ngModel)]="model">
```