# Angular ngbDatePicker - do something when user selects a date from Calendar

Tags: angular, ngb-datepicker

**Goal**: I would like to reset the text color in the matinput to black when a user selects (any) date from the ngbDatePicker CALENDAR.
I set it to make text red if they type in a future date. I want it to go back to black if they select a date from the Calendar UI

**Problem**: I can't seem to detect when a user selects a date from the calendar. I don't need to know what date they select, only that they selected SOMETHING.

[image: ngbDatePicker]

**What I've tried**:
The following in the html

- (change)=

  - doesnt do anything
- (select)=

  - doesnt seem to do anything
- (click)=

  - this only registers when I click in the matinput text box, not when I
    click the calendar

As per SO articles: [How to detect date selection in ng-bootstrap Datepicker on input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48903442/how-to-detect-date-selection-in-ng-bootstrap-datepicker-on-input-field) , [How to detect bootstrap datetimepicker change events within angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36087762/how-to-detect-bootstrap-datetimepicker-change-events-within-angular2) , https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples

**TypeScript**:

```
onDateSelected() {
        this.dateRed = false;
        console.log("dateRed value: " + this.dateRed);
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="input-group date-field-90">
        <input matInput formControlName="dateOfBirth" class="form-control" (keypress)="dateEnter($event)"
                    [placeholder]="dateplaceholder" [ngClass]="{'dateRed' : dateRed}" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" [maxDate]="currentDate" (change)="onDateSelected()" [(ngModel)]="dob1"
                    #dobDate required>
        <mat-icon (click)="d.toggle()">event</mat-icon>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.dateRed{
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it, it was (dateSelect)=

(dateSelect)="onDateSelected()"